# gmapping algorithm

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
I would like to know the algorithms used in gmapping and depthimage_to_laserscan.someoone please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227239/gmapping-algorithm/) by [niel](https://answers.ros.org/users/25707/niel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For `gmapping`, you can check http://openslam.org/gmapping.html,

*Giorgio Grisetti, Cyrill Stachniss, and Wolfram Burgard: Improved Techniques for Grid Mapping with Rao-Blackwellized Particle Filters, IEEE Transactions on Robotics, Volume 23, pages 34-46, 2007* ([link](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Estachnis/pdf/grisetti07tro.pdf))

and

*Giorgio Grisetti, Cyrill Stachniss, and Wolfram Burgard: Improving Grid-based SLAM with Rao-Blackwellized Particle Filters by Adaptive Proposals and Selective Resampling, In Proc. of the IEEE International Conference on Robotics and Automation (ICRA), 2005* ([link](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Estachnis/pdf/grisetti05icra.pdf))

For `depthimage_to_laserscan` you can visit [its wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan) and check the [source code](https://github.com/ros-perception/depthimage_to_laserscan).

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1